# What ways are there to leave a script running, while my pc is not running/not being used?

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2, data-collection

I am currently to pulling Tweets through the X/Twitter API, now I would like to leave the script running over the weekend to collect as many tweets as possible (within Twitters limits ofc) to later analyze them/work with them.
As of right now I have the python script in VS Code and saved on the company laptop.

My "last resort" idea would be to just use a while true loop and leave the PC running, but obviously that's a lot of wasted power on my part.

Could I just save the script as a document in a folder on my company's server (I don't have special rights for that) and let it run from there somehow? (I don't have immediate access to a raspberry pi, sadly that won't be an option)

I'm not necessarily looking for a perfect guide or answer, some ideas or recommendations what to look into  would already be very appreciated.

Comment: If you're running this at your place of employment then that sounds like more of a question for your employer's IT team than for us.  We can tell you that in order for the script to be running, something has to be running it.  Whether that something is your workstation or a server in your company's network isn't really for us to say.

Comment: If you do a `time.sleep(60)` in your loop to run once a minute, that doesn't use extra power.  But, of course, the company laptop will need to be running all weekend.